# Calculator wait for user input (Discord.js)

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I am doing a Discord bot, which idea would be rather simple. It asks the user for 3 numbers, and what should be done with them (add or remove). Currently the command works when you add them all as a single line (!calc add 1 1 1) and then prints the result (1 + 1 + 1 = 3). However i want to know how to set the bot ask the number inputs as 3 different questions, instead of needing to telling them all at once.

```
     module.exports = {
name: 'calc',
description: "calculating",
execute(message, args){
    let method = args[0];
    let firstNumber = Number(args[1]);
    let secondNumber = Number(args[2]);
    let thirdNumber = Number(args[3]);



    const operations = ['add', 'remove'];

    if(!method) return message.reply('please select add or remove');

    if (!args[1]) return message.reply('please state first number');

    if (!args[2]) return message.reply('please state second number');

    if (!args[3]) return message.reply('please state third number');

    if (isNaN(firstNumber)) return message.reply('number 1 missing');

    if (isNaN(secondNumber)) return message.reply('number 2 missing');

    if (isNaN(thirdNumber)) return message.reply('number 3 missing');

    if (method === 'add') {

        let doMath = firstNumber + secondNumber + thirdNumber
        message.channel.send(`${firstNumber} + ${secondNumber} + ${thirdNumber} = ${doMath}`);

        if (method === 'remove') {

            let doMath = firstNumber - secondNumber - thirdNumber
            message.channel.send(`${firstNumber} - ${secondNumber} - ${thirdNumber} = ${doMath}`);
   }
  }
 }
}
```

To show what happens in Discord itself currently:
[calculation process add](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7daQ2.jpg)

Im myself new to coding, so things like this give me problems. Thanks already for answers.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing *"if statements"* with these

```
if(method == undefined)             return  message.reply('please select add or remove');

if (!args[1] == undefined)           return message.reply('please state first number');

if (!args[2] == undefined)           return message.reply('please state second number');

if (!args[3] == undefined)           return message.reply('please state third number');

if (isNaN(firstNumber) | firstNumber === "")              return message.reply('number 1 missing');

if (isNaN(secondNumber | secondNumber === ""))             return message.reply('number 2 missing');

if (isNaN(thirdNumber) | thirdNumber === "")              return message.reply('number 3 missing');
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. However it still ends up on the same solution, you need to type all details at once. Im aiming for the bot to first ask "give first number" and then after typing it the bot would ask "give second number" and then same deal with the 3rd input.